# How to add a sticky element to a tumblr theme?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tumblr

So I've been making a basic tumblr theme (haven't added the posts or anything else yet) and I've been trying to make the menu bar remain at the top as you scroll but it's not working. I don't know if the code is wrong or maybe I'm putting the JavaScript in the wrong place ?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<title>Title</title>
<style type="text/css">
#container {
position:fixed;
overflow:scroll;
overflow-x:hidden;
margin-left:375px;
margin-top:88px;
height:475px;
width:500px;
background-color:#ddd;
 }

 *,
*:after,
*::before {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
margin: 0;
font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}


#color-1 {
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 1em 1em;
margin: 1em;
text-align: center;

}

#color-1 {
background: #bed0ff;
}


#nav-1 a {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
margin: 5px 5px;
outline: none;
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 1px;
font-weight: 400;
text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3); 
font-size: 1 em;
}

#nav-1 a:hover,
#nav-1 a:focus {
outline: none;
}


#nav-1 a::after {
display: block;

}

#nav-1 a::after {
margin-top: 5px;
width: 0;
height: 2px;
background-color: #fff;
content: '';
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transition: width 0.3s, opacity 0.6s;
-moz-transition: width 0.3s, opacity 0.6s;
transition: width 0.3s, opacity 0.6s; 

}

#nav-1 a:hover::after,
#nav-1 a:focus::after {
opacity: 1;
width: 100%;
}


#color-1.stick {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
z-index: 10000;
border-radius: 0 0 0.5em 0.5em;
}

</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function sticky_relocate() {
var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
var div_top = $('#anchor').offset().top;
if (window_top > div_top) {
    $('#color-1').addClass('stick');
} else {
    $('#color-1').removeClass('stick');
}
}

$(function () {
$(window).scroll(sticky_relocate);
sticky_relocate();
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">


<div id="anchor"></div>
<div id="color-1">
<div id="nav-1">
  <a href="#">Link</a>
  <a href="#">Link</a>
  <a href="#">Link</a>
  <a href="#">Link</a>
  <a href="#">Link</a>
</div>
 </div>
  text

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I've been trying to make the menu bar remain at the top as you scroll...

If you simply want your element to remain at the top as you scroll you can do this with straight css.

```
.sticky-element {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Add `sticky-element` css to the `class` you'd like to have a fixed position at the top of the screen; perhaps `#nav-1`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have jQuery on the test page but I'm assuming you have it on your site But if not then that is why your script is not working. I'm not really sure what you are doing. But I created your test page and added jQuery and your code does do something... If you need to add jQuery I suggest using a google cdn.

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

I would suggest in the future opening the dev panel f12 or ctrl-shift-i and looking at the console for script errors.  Hopefully that is a little bit helpful.